# TCPDF z-index of the element

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to work on TCPDF and encounter a problem. Following is my code segment form a function. Just simply get a template PDF and add some content.

```
$pdf->AddPage();            
$pdf->setSourceFile($file_path);  
$html = '<div style="z-index:99999;background-color:yellow;color:blue;">&nbsp;PAGE 1&nbsp;</div>';         
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, true, true, false, ''); 
$pdf->RoundedRect($base_x, $base_y, 60, 22, 2.50, '1111', 'DF', ['color' => array(0, 128, 0)], array(200, 200, 200));
$pdf->useTemplate($pdf->importPage(1), 0, 0, 207);
```

Template PDF file has some content such as logo and text. My problem is, both newly added HTML tag and Rectangle are staying behind the logo and text content of the pdf template.

I want these new elements to stay up front like we did with z-index in CSS.  Please help.

Comment: I don't see any useTemplate() call?

Comment: Yes. That was the reason. I put the useTemplate() call at the last accidentally. The problem is solved now.